# Have you found an way to programmatically create site collection Information Management Policy yet?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Have you found a way to create a site collection IMP programmatically on SharePoint 2010, 2013 or 2016 yet?

"I need to be programmatically do the steps that are mentioned in the link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-information-management-policy-for-a-site-collection-a5808074-ddcd-4ed2-a9cc-228ba6318343?CorrelationId=e001ab83-0910-4f34-bf91-bcc7ee3f3b36&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010099553"

I need to do the same thing either in Powershell or code. Could you please share if have a solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, You have to follow this blog: ["Programmatically Create Custom Information Management Policy"](https://joannecklein.com/2013/02/07/programmatically-create-custom-information-management-policy/)

Some important Steps from the blog:

- 2 Namespaces to call out (`Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy`, `Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository`)
- Create a custom list policy by creating an XML string defining the first retention stage with a Delete action
- Create a method to both create and set the custom policy on the library passing in the retentionXML created above and the library where the archived forms are housed
- Declare each form a record: